# Pine Script compiler type error in 'if' blocks

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to get familiar with pine script.
For that I'm trying to write a simple strategy, that will place boxes on the chart.
But I'm getting the following error and maybe you can help me out with this.
The compiler error message says:

```
lines 31:45: Return type of one of the 'if' blocks is not compatible with return type of other block(s) (series[box]; void)
```

For me it is hard to understand the meaning of the error message.
I checked the indentation and the types for comparison.
Do you have any idea about that?

The code is the following:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
//@version=4
strategy("My Script", overlay=true)

// run on daily chart

// globals
var box[] up_boxes = array.new_box(0)
var float[] up_boxes_closes = array.new_float(0)

var box[] down_boxes = array.new_box(0)
var float[] down_boxes_closes = array.new_float(0)


// check for new boxes
// upper
if (low > high[1])
    array.push(up_boxes, box.new(left=bar_index[1], top=high[1], bottom=low, right=bar_index))
    array.push(up_boxes_closes, high[1])
// lower
else if (high < low[1])
    array.push(down_boxes, box.new(left=bar_index[1], top=low[1], bottom=high, right=bar_index))
    array.push(down_boxes_closes, low[1])


// check if boxes can be removed (no longer updated)
for i = 0 to array.size(up_boxes) - 1
    // reomve from the array, if our price is higher, else extend it
    float close_price = array.get(up_boxes_closes, i)
    float actual_price = high[0]
    if (actual_price >= close_price)
        array.remove(up_boxes_closes, i)
        array.remove(up_boxes, i)
    else
        id = array.get(up_boxes, i)
        box.set_right(id, bar_index)

// check if boxes can be removed (no longer updated)
//for j = 0 to array.size(down_boxes) - 1
//    // reomve from the array, if our price is lower, else extend it
//    if (low < array.get(down_boxes_closes, j))
//        array.remove(down_boxes_closes, j)
//        array.remove(down_boxes, j)
//    else
//        box.set_right(array.get(down_boxes, j), bar_index)
```

Comment: Your `if` and `else` blocks need to return same type. First is array.remove() => void();
second is series[box]. As rumpypumpydumpy mentioned, use different `if` blocks.

Comment: @StarrLucky Wait: Yes thanks, with the clarification, the docs actually make sense for me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

substitute `else` with `if actual_price < close_price` instead